# Segmentation fault for numbers too big for Ackermann's function

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault, long-integer, ackermann

Why is this failing? I have written Ackermann's function in C and used longs to make sure that no number will be too small. Yet, when I go above (including) 4 for m and n, it gives me a `segmentation fault: 11`. Does anyone know why?

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int ackermann(long m, long n) {
      if (m == 0)
              return n + 1;
      else if (m > 0 && n == 0)
              return ackermann(m - 1, 1);
      else if (m > 0 && n > 0)
              return ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1));
  }

  int main() {
          long result = ackermann(4, 4);
          printf("%lu", result);
  }
```

Comment: On many systems `long` is the same size as `int`. Try `long long` or `int64_t`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Table_of_values. Ackermann(4, 4) is a number with thousands of digits. There is no C type that comes anywhere close to storing that number.

Comment: Segmentation fault... now where did "Stack Overflow" get its name from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have written Ackermann's function in C and used longs to make sure
> that no number will be too small.

The size of an `unsigned long long` is 2^6 (64) bits.  The size of the result for `ackermann(4, 2)` is greater than 2^16 (65536) bits.  You can compute `ackermann(4, 1)` and `ackermann(5, 0)` but not much with larger values of `m` and `n`.

Code-wise, you use a *signed* `long` when an *unsigned* `long` might serve you better and you declare the `ackermann()` function itself to return a `signed int` which is inconsistent.  (Your `ackermann()` function also has a fourth exit point that isn't properly defined, compiler-wise.)  Here's a rework of your code using `unsigned long long` which still won't get you very far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long ackermann(unsigned long long m, unsigned long long n) {
    if (m == 0) {
        return n + 1;
    }

    if (m > 0 && n == 0) {
        return ackermann(m - 1, 1);
    }

    return ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1));
}

int main() {
    unsigned long long result = ackermann(5, 0);
    printf("%llu\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```